# T400 wireless adaptor not work

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lenovo, thinkpad, adapter

My wireless card `wlan0` on Thinkpad T400 can work for a short while, after each booting into Ubuntu 12.04. But after a while, maybe an hour later, it starts not working. Here are the outputs of commands I run following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers 
and https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

I wonder what might be the problem and the solution? Thanks.

```
$ nm-tool

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```

---

```
$ lshw -C network

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial:
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-60-generic-pae firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:f4200000-f4201fff
```

---

```
$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               362337  0 
mac80211              436493  4 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib,iwlwifi
cfg80211              178877  3 rt2x00lib,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

---

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
$ sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Input/output error

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

---

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Seems this solve my question http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1686641&page=2&p=11254836#post11254836. But I don't understand why wireless power management will be the reason of the problem.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. problem is back again.